# UISlider doesn't response at max edge position

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiviewcontroller, uislider, touches

I have implemented UISlider using [DoubleSlider](https://github.com/doukasd/iOS-Components/tree/master/Controls/DoubleSlider) The problem is when my view appears and my slider handles are in min and max position by then.

**Symptoms**:

- When the view is loaded maxHandle doesn't response to touches for a
  long period of time. When  its finally responsive it works well but
  it takes about 5 seconds for it to wake.
- This situation repeats when
  I move the handle to max edge of slider.

**Solutions tried**:

- I have debugged the problem and it figures out that the handle
  doesn't get touch events. I wonder why, cause it is working properly
  after some time.
- I have checked touchable area and made it really big
  (80x120px)

What else could cause this behaviour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that when I made a slider area that narrow, that touch started between the edge of the screen, the slider didn't accept it as a slider's starting touch. Making slider's active area so brod that the gap between slider's edge and edge of the screen was smaller than touch area solved the problem.